# Substitution Reactions; Stability of Carbocations

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was wondering which is more stable: a secondary carbocation or a primary carbocation that has resonance stabilization?

I was reading through the organic chemistry text, it said that resonance stabilizes carbocation.

However it did not explain the which which is more stable then the other.

This is not a homework question. I am genuinely curious.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎

Comment: it is generally admitted that resonance effects are stronger that inductive effect.

Answer (score 0):

The order of stability of carbocation is 3°>2°>1° of course stabilisation by resonance is more worthy then inductive effect. You can get more detail on wikipidea regarding it

Answer (score 0):

If it's the case that both primary and secondary carbonation is undergoing the same resonance then we can say 2° is more stable due to added inductive effect by the alkyl groups. 
Now it can also depend on the extent of resonance (the number of resonance structures) the carbocation is undertaking. There can also be hyper conjugation stability for the carbocations.
It is also important for us to consider the stability order of carbocations.[image: This is how it goes]

This stability order too depends on the factors mentioned above.
Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a primary carbocation with resonance stabilization us more stable than secondary carbocation because resonance stabilization effect > inductive effect.